# How do you know when data is received without the SerialDataReceived Event using .Net SerialPort

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm using the SerialPort class in a library, and use the library in a unity project to communicate with an other device using serial communication.

This all works fine when I'm using the dll in any application besides unity.  But for some reason unity wont call the SerialDataReceived event, my guess is that mono develop is not supporting the event.

I tested that my serial connection is receiving data because. I can read the data from the port. The problem is that I don't know when to begin reading it, and the result is that I always get a TimeOut exeption sooner or later.

So is there a way other than the SerialDataReceived Event to know that my port has received data.

Comment: If you don't like timeout exceptions then simply set the ReadTimeout property to -1.

Answer (score 0):

Periodically check the SerialPort.BytesToRead Property.

Comment: I have done that but the problem is unity doesn't execute the code after i call the SerialPort.BytesToRead. I don't know why it gets stuck here.